# Incomplete list of timezones generated by PHP

Tags: php, timezone, region

I've tried generating the complete set of timezones as specified in http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php (except UTC) by using the following code:

```
$zones = timezone_identifiers_list();

print_r($zones);
```

But this list seems to skip ~ 50 regions, eg: Pacific/Samoa (as compared to http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

What are we doing wrong?

phpinfo() shows:

```
PHP Version 5.3.4
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) 

$ uname -r
2.6.18-028stab070.14
```

---

Edit #2

```
date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   0.system
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    UTC
```

Comment: What OS and PHP version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your timezone database might not be up-to-date.

Try following the link at the bottom of the [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) page :

> The latest version of the timezone
>   database can be installed via PECL's »
>   [timezonedb](http://pecl.php.net/get/timezonedb).

---

**Edit after the comments :** to update your timezone database, as you are on a Linux system, you can use the `pecl` command *(I just tried this on my Ubuntu machine)* :

```
pecl upgrade timezonedb
```

This will download the new version, and compile it.

Then, if you enable the new `timezonedb` extension, your PHP should use an uptodate database :

```
php -dextension=timezonedb.so -i | grep Timezone
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2011.5
Timezone Database => external
Alternative Timezone Database => enabled
Timezone Database Version => 2011.5
```

If I try without enabling that new extension, I get the same kind of thing you had before :

```
php -i | grep Timezone
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
```

Comment: Furthermore, the DB version in use can be found at phpinfo()'s output ("date" section).

Comment: @matt74tm - Unix `tzdata` != PHP `timezonedb`.

Comment: @Álvaro @Pascal - i have installed the timezone db via yum install tzdata and the version is the output from rpm -q tzdata

Comment: @matt I've updated my answer with some additional informations ; hope this help :-)

Comment: @Pascal - thanks! i've made a bit of progress: php -i | grep Timezone
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2011.5
Timezone Database => external
Alternative Timezone Database => enabled
Timezone Database Version => 2011.5
However, it still is not outputting Pacific/Samoa!!

Comment: @Pascal, @Álvaro G. Vicario - any thoughts on what's going wrong with my system?

Comment: Not really, I have to admit :-(

Answer (score 1):

Tested this on my server. No problem at all. Maybe this is a server-related issue?

output: [timezones.php](http://www.karativ.de/so/timezones.php)

source-code:

```
<?php

foreach(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $zone) {

    echo $zone.'<br/>';

}   

?>
```

Best,
Christian

Comment: hmm - doesnt give Samoa for me ... :)

Comment: on your server or on my server? this is important as we can exclude the php environment. FYI: I am running MacOS X 10.6.7 on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

As [Pascal MARTIN points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776392/incomplete-list-of-timezones-generated-by-php/5776493#5776493), the PHP time zone database is a PECL package. Since you are using a Linux host you shouldn't have any problem:

```
pecl install timezonedb
```

... or:

```
pecl upgrade timezonedb
```

## Update:

I found a link with CentOS specific instructions:

- http://www.electrictoolbox.com/correct-php-timezone/

You can also do a search:

```
C:\>pecl search timezonedb
Retrieving data...0%
MATCHED PACKAGES, CHANNEL PECL.PHP.NET:
=======================================
PACKAGE    STABLE/(LATEST) LOCAL
timezonedb 2011.5 (stable)       Timezone Database to be used with PHP's date and time functions
```

Comment: I did this: pecl upgrade timezonedb ; added at the end of /etc/php.ini extension=timezonedb.so ; restarted apache but no change in output

Comment: ie, i still dont see Pacific/Samoa!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling timezone_identifiers_list(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC). That worked for me. (Found this solution from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873059/323330)