# What is the difference between tzdata database and timezonedb?

Tags: php, timezone, php-extension

There was a timezone issue in a PHP application running on Fedora I worked on and I am curious to know the difference between tzdata and timezonedb and how does PHP use them to calculate the timezome?

The issue was that 'Europe/Moscow' should be GMT+3 but PHP added one hour i.e. GMT+4. 
Most of the solutions are about running

```
pecl upgrade timezonedb
```

check [Incomplete list of timezones generated by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776392/incomplete-list-of-timezones-generated-by-php)

Without installing timezonedb extension, we updated tzdata

```
yum update tzdata
```

and then the issue was fixed!

So, Does PHP use tzdata if timezonedb is not installed or what?

PHP: 5.5.18

OS : Fedora 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the databases (tzdata) ships with PHP, this is used by default. A later version of the db can to be installed separately on the system via PECL.

Pecl [timezonedb extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) indicates there is an embedded db by default.

> This extension is a drop-in replacement for the builtin timezone
>   database that comes with PHP. You should only install this extension
>   in case you need to get a later version of the timezone database than
>   the one that ships with PHP.

Comment: Thanks. So if timezonedb is installed, PHP uses it. If not - my case -it will use tzdata. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe that's correct. My guess is various OS' are taking care of some configuration details when you install an external db, but not 100% on that. Found a better link on the subject though and have updated my answer.

Comment: Ugh, actually, still not that great of info; looking for a better link, but think that's the case anyway.

Comment: Found a decent link finally; looks like this is what you've installed.

Comment: Thanks again, So, I think PHP uses tzdata by default.

Answer (score -1):

For centos 6 users with php 5.5+ use this:

```
yum -y update tzdata
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
pecl install --ignore-errors  timezonedb
echo "extension=timezonedb.so" > /etc/php.d/timezonedb.ini
```